# How to get the difference of two list in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've two lists like

```
List<String> LISTONE=new List<String>()
```

and

```
List<String> LISTTWO=new List<String>()
```

and which contains

```
LISTONE   "A"
          "B"
          "C"
LISTTWO   "A"
          "D"
          "E"
```

and the required out put is

```
LISTTEMP  "B"   
          "C"
          "D"
          "E"
```

is there any way to do this using  LINQ

Comment: by what mechanism has 'c,d,e' been selected as the appropriate output? what do they signify, in the context?

Comment: Are you sure "B" shouldnt be in there too?

Comment: @ Jamiec & David Hedlund : Edited in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done using *Except()* and *Concat()* LINQ methods:

```
LISTONE.Except(LISTTWO).Concat(LISTTWO.Except(LISTONE))
```

Comment: this looks promising. this will include "B" which isn't in OP's `listtemp`, but that's possibly a typo on OP's part...

Answer (score 2):

```
LISTONE.Except(LISTTWO).Union(LISTTWO.Except(LISTONE)) //.Distinct()?
```

EDIT: The Union method implements Distinct behaviour, so Distinct would be redundant.

Comment: can the result from that query ever be non-distinct?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. Thinking about it a little more, I suppose Union is actually an implementation of UNION (SQL) behaviour as opposed to Concat which is equivalent to UNION ALL, so the Distinct is most likely superfluous.

Comment: regardless of how the union works, if you concatinate two lists containing only the items that are not in the other list, it seems that you could logically never end up with duplicates with `UNION` *or* `UNION ALL`

Comment: Ah, but supposing one of the lists contains two identical items that don't occur in the second? I guess the OP should tighten up their question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want "All elements which do not appear in both lists", in which case, as my note above mentions, "B" should also be in there. this is the linq'ed answer.

```
one.Concat(two).Except(one.Intersect(two))
```